# Variable in Dictionary Value String Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing some values and a SQL query string to a dictionary in python. I would like to use one of the values as a filter criteria for the SQL but I am not able to pass it in. What am I doing wrong?

```
My_DICT = [
    {'Sale_Type' : 'Car', 'Sale_Length' : 5, "Query_String" : "select * from Sales where Length > %s" % (My_DICT [Sale_Length])}
    ]
```

So what I want is for the query to be:

```
select * from Sales where Length > 5
```

Comment: 1) `My_DICT` is defined as a `list` above. Is it defined elsewhere as a `dict`? 2) You are indexing your variable within the assignment of the same variable. Create separate variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
My_DICT = {'Sale_Type' : 'Car', 'Sale_Length' : 5, "Query_String" : ""}
My_DICT['Query_String'] = "select * from Sales where Length > %s" % My_DICT['Sale_Length']
```

**-- EDIT --**

Considering your input example, you have a list of dictionaries in My_DICT. You could do it like this:

```
for element in My_DICT:
    element['Query_String'] = "select * from Sales where Length > %s" % element['Sale_Length']
```

Comment: this works but I was just hoping to have it more consolidated

Comment: What do you mean by 'more consolidated'?

Comment: SO that is two lines of code, my example was just one. The full dictionary will be much bigger but I just put in a snippet.

Comment: If I correctly got what you are trying to do, my edit should help. I don't know a more 'pythonic' way of doing that, though.

Comment: If that's a user-provided data set, then that query is entirely vulnerable to  SQL injection.  There are better approaches to that without exposing one to SQL injection.